# Can I use accessor methods in a constructor?

Tags: perl, oop, constructor, accessor

I am writing a simple Perl module that handles time and date information.  Below is a simplified version of the constructor and one of the accessor methods:

```
package Time;

# Constructor
sub new {
    my $class = shift;
    my %args  = @_;

    # Create an empty object
    my $self = bless {};

    # Get input arguments
    my $second = exists $args{'second'} ? $args{'second'} : (localtime)[0];

    # Use the accessor to validate and populate object data
    $self->second($second);

    return $self;
}

# Second accessor
sub second {
    my $self   = shift;
    my $second = shift;

    # Input validation
    if (defined $second) {
        if ($second =~ m{^\d+$} && $second >= 0 && $second <= 59) {
            $self->{'second'} = $second;
        }
        else {
            die "'second' must be an integer between 0 and 59!";
        }
    }

    return $self->{'second'};
}
```

My question is... ***Is it acceptable to use an accessor in object construction in Perl?***

Using the accessor inside of the constructor makes it so I don't need all of the validation code in the constructor itself since the input is validated by the accessor, but is this bad practice?

Is there any reason I would not want to do this?

Comment: Perl doesn't have a concept of constructor. `new` is just a static method like any other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes**, you can do that.

But from an OOP perspective it might make sense to move that code into an `init` method, so the constructor only *creates* the object. It's basically done after you've called `bless`.

```
sub new {
    my $class = shift;

    # Create an empty object
    my $self = bless {};

    # initialize the object
    $self->init(@_);

    return $self;
}

sub init {
    my ($self, %args) = @_;

    # Get input arguments
    my $second = exists $args{'second'} ? $args{'second'} : (localtime)[0];

    # Use the accessor to validate and populate object data
    $self->second($second);

    return;
}
```

---

Have you considered using [Moose](http://p3rl.org/Moose)? You can also use [Type::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Type::Tiny) for your type constraints, even if you want to stick with *manual oop*.

Comment: I have used Moose before, but it isn't readily available on the server I am working on and there is a long process to request new software or libraries that I just don't want to deal with...  I do really like the idea of an init function though.  It looks quite elegant.  Thanks!

Comment: @tjwrona1992 you can go with Moo, and in the worst case [fatpack](https://metacpan.org/pod/App::FatPacker) it with your application.

Comment: And on the other hand, if you deal with it once, you have it for all your projects. Having a process is soooo much better than most people here complaining that they are not allowed to use CPAN. ;)